# Django file upload with Ajax-fueled progress bar

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, ajax, django

I am relatively new to Django and even newer to JavaScript, so excuse my greenhorn question. The situation is like this:

1) I have a website for file uploading, coded out in Django, with some of the logic like the one below:

```
def page_query(request):
    ...
    if request.method == 'POST':
       ...
       file_entry = file_form(request.POST, request.FILES)

       if file_entry.is_valid():
           if request.FILES.get('filename', False) != False:
               f = request.FILES['filename']
               fname = time_id + '_' + case_id + '_.ext'
               file_check = data_admin.upload_file(f, fname, upload_path)
               upload_file_path = os.path.join(upload_path, fname)
```

data_admin.upload_file() is a custom function defined in another module of my project with function boiling down to:

```
with open(upload_path + fname, 'wb+') as destination:
    for chunk in f.chunks():
        destination.write(chunk)
```

2) I wanted to add some sort of upload progress indication to my website, and in a lot of sources I have seen people recommending jQuery's Ajax solution, which boils down to the code below:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#form_id').on('submit', function(event) {
    // event.preventDefault();

    var post_data = new FormData($("#form_id")[0]);

    $.ajax({
        xhr: function() {
          var xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest();

          xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", function(evt) {
            var percent = Math.round(evt.loaded/evt.total * 100)
            console.log(percent)
            $('#complaint_query_button').attr('disabled', true)
            $('#complaint_query_button').get(0).innerText = "Upload status: " + percent + '%'
          }, false);

          xhr.upload.addEventListener("load", function(evt) {
            $('#complaint_query_button').css('background-color', 'green').delay(2000)
            $('#complaint_query_button').get(0).innerText = "COMPLETE, refreshing..."
            // setTimeout(location.reload.bind(location), 10000);

          }, false);

          return xhr;
        },
          url: window.location.href,// to allow add and edit
          // url: window.location.reload(),
          type: "POST",
          data: post_data,
          processData: false,
          contentType: false,
          success: function(result) {
              //
        }
      });
  })
```

The above solution worked for me like a charm, and I have a submit button which indicates upload's progress in %s, however, I think I do not completely understand what is exactly happening with all that in place. **I have seen files attached in the file input HTML elements get uploaded twice to my destination on the server.** Moreover, the upload progress indicated on the submit button by Ajax command does not line up with my browser's upload progress info displayed in the bottom-left side of the page. 
I am really confused by the above - am I creating 2 upload streams (one with Django, the other with Ajax)? How can I reconcile them?
I am open to suggestions on how to deal with this issue, or maybe there is a Django-native module which takes care of file upload progress?

Thank you.

**UPDATE 19 Sep 2018**
Still had no luck figuring this one out. Would be obliged to anyone who'll find a moment to share their opinion with me. Apologies for a shameless bump up.

Comment: Bumping it up in hope of someone answering my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, after a big trial and error run with this matter, I have finally cracked the problem - the url argument had to be changed from "window.location.href" to "#", and all problems I have described above stopped immediately. After adding in views.py's page_query function a JSON response at the end of the POST method block, I ended up having a web site which does file transfer and updates the user about the status of the upload without a need to be re-rendered after each form submission.

Would love to learn from someone more knowledgeable than myself, what does this "#" sign in there really do in there, as it has been a game-changer for me.

Comment: I was looking for a similar answer myself, and as a fellow noob as far as I understand is '#' represents the current page, and your ajax is sending the POST request to some page, and that is the current page where you're handling the POST requests in your views.py. I watched a youtube vide, maybe this will help, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f-wXTpbNWoM